# Is there any word for staying at home and do nothing?

Tags: word-request

Is there any word to describe the action of staying at home and doing nothing and thinking nothing, not being spellbound but only the result of laziness or tiredness, or simply not wanting to do anything?
If you know something in Chinese as 发呆, there are two aspects of meaning or contexts for that word, one is what results from too much thinking on a particular thing or concentrating too much on some sort of emotion like a boy's affection for a  girl or someone's nostalgia; another context is what I've mentioned in the question that someone appears to be doing nothing in a particular place, especially in a place of comfort and relief that you can be at your ease when you are not engaged in anything.
I just can't find a word or phrase to describe or be equal to such a state.

Comment: Try "vegetating" or the abbreviated version "vegging out" :D Dictionary reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veg%20out

Comment: Consider [lazing around](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Phrasal_Verbs/L/laze_around_2226.php) (or possibly [cocooning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocooning_(behaviour)))

Comment: **Chilling** is an American English colloquialism for "just sitting around doing nothing".

Comment: An AmE colloquialism for "absolutely nothing" or "nothing at all" is **diddly squat**. *I'm doing diddly squat.* But it can have wider uses:  *Some of our elected officials know diddly squat about history.*

Comment: I'm from the UK. I would call it "vegetating".   It doesn't have any emotional connotations however.  For something that causes you to think/concentrate too much about one thing to the detriment of other activities, you could call that "obsessing".

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, very helpful for a foreign English learner, like me.

Answer (score 1):

"Chilling / chilling out" given by swmcdonnell is good, but I prefer **to laze about**. From [TheFreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lazing+about):

> To relax or spend time idly; to do nothing or very little.
> *It's a gorgeous day outside, so you kids get off your butts and quit **lazing about**! I can't wait to go on my vacation and **laze about** the beach for two weeks!*

Answer (score 0):

Most of the terms for this, at least in American English, are colloqualisms, and a few were mentioned in the comments. Some that come to mind for me are:

- Chill, chill out, chilling at home
- Vegetate, veg, veg out, vegging  at home
- Crash, crash out (this can also mean you slept)
- Being lazy, being worthless, being useless, being "a bum"
- Being a "bump on the log" (older)

Comment: How would you use "veg" in a sentence? (I don't mean  *vegging* or *vegging out*)  *Sunday mornings I veg* (?) Do you have any references to support these solutions?

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful.